# integrating MVC framework in a finished project

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm working for this JAVA EE project for school. I almost finished but I realized that it's demanded that we should use an MVC framework (spring or whatever)
What I've done so far is making a jsp page that sends the form data to a HttpServlet and then the servlet output the result.
How can I integrate a MVC framework without remaking the whole work, especially I'm close to deadline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts) (STS) application then you can easily create a template Spring MVC project. It should then be a quick process to drop in the code you already have.

From the New Project drop-down select Spring Template Project, then choose Spring MVC project. It will include support for Maven so that all dependencies are resolved for you.

Place your servlet code into the generated `HomeController` class (you *will* need to make changes), and your JSP into the `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views` folder.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How close is close for the deadline. I've never found configuring frameworks for the first time to be trivial - sorting out dependencies and all. [This tutorial](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/) I think coveres the quickstarts. [Spring mvc's docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) are always a solid reference. The important parts for you right now are 16.2 The DispatcherServlet, 16.3 Implementing Controllers, 16.3.1, and 16.3.2

If you are familiar with maven, you can generate a project structure with an archetype, [appfuse-basic-spring](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is definitely going to require some bit of rewriting on your side. The upside is that from what you have written it already seems you are following the MVC pattern, so at least it would be more of 1:1 porting than reorganizing the code and rewriting from scratch.

The first step would be to fiddle with configuration - e.g. add the Spring context and the MVC Filter.
Basically, the jsp could easily remain a jsp, since Spring MVC supports a JSPView, it could require minor modifications, but nothing shocking. Then, you would have to change the Servlet to a Spring MVC Controller. Spring MVC Controllers could just receive the HttpRequest as an additional method parameter, so that would be a comfortable starting point (moving the same  servlet code to the controller).

After that you could start making the app more Spring MVC like - you can have a look at PetClinic or at any of the more-basic Spring MVC demo-apps.

So in short:

1. Add configuration
2. Port code (Servlet -> controller; jsp -> jsp)
3. Modify to achieve final result